# Sharepoint 2013 anonymous access and the everyone and NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm running a SharePoint 2013 on premise system.  My site collection is made up entirely of SharePoint publishing sites.  Anonymous Access is enabled and has read permissions on the entire application.  I also created a 'Home Visitors' group that also give read access to 'Everyone' and 'NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users'.  This group has read access to a library that I'm trying to access.

My account that is a site collection administrator on the site can view the document.  I can also view the same document from a browser that does not authenticate to the server automatically.  However, I have a domain administrator account that, when it tries to access the same document, it says I do not have permission.   How is it that my domain admin account does not fall into 'NT AUTHORITY/Authenticated Users' or 'Everyone'?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can make sure that your administrator user is also added in WSS_ADMIN_WPG 
WSS_WPG

groups to access it